# How to judiciously apply indexes in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

Indexes are mostly used to improve the speed of database query, and most preferably applied on the primary key of the table , but however this may not be the case always.

I want to know the decisions that go into applying an index and thus achieving the best results possible.

For not my knowledge for indexes is limited to applying it to the primary key only , in what circumstances would i apply it otherwise

Comment: should i be deleting such questions , this question is going to close down ?

Comment: Yes, it's a very interesting topic but unfortunately it's not going to fit in the QA format of SO.

Comment: should i make it more specific ? @dystroy

Comment: This could be a solution. But be aware that it's very hard to expose in a concise way the complete requirements of a non trivial table indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As widely as they are used, an `index` is best used on any columns that are used often in both a statement's `WHERE` clause and `ORDER BY` clause.

Take for instance, the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
    `id` int,
    `name` varchar(255),
    `phone` varchar(10),
    `state` varchar(50),
    `city` varchar(100),
    `zip` int
);
```

By default, you'll probably only have an index on the `id` column. Now, let's say you have 20k "people" in your database. When searching by any field other than the id field, you may start to notice a bit of lag. This is where indexes will come in.

There's a good chance that you won't be searching by the `phone` field (possible, but not likely), so we wouldn't index that one. However, searching by `state`/`city`/`zip` are more likely. When you search by city/state, you often search with them both together with a `WHERE` clause similar to:

```
WHERE state = 'Florida' AND city = 'Miami';
```

Because they're often-used together, you should have an index created with *both* fields (see [`multiple-column indexes`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)). On the other hand, when you search by `zip`, you often do so without a city/state attached, such as:

```
WHERE zip = 12345;
```

With this, you'll create an index just with the zip field.

Also, it is worth a note that indexes take up not only space, but need to be modified during any `INSERT` or `UPDATE` on a table with them. If you have numerous indexes and a *lot* of records, a single `INSERT`'s time can start to be noticed. So, be sure that you actually need the additional performance boost that the index will give before adding them like salt+pepper.

Comment: preciseeeeeely what i was looking for , a very neat example, thank you @newfurniturey